# iWork '09 collection of shapes as single movable object

Tags: iwork, iwork-pages, shapes

Is is possible to create a kind of shape-'group' in pages, which allows you to maintain and/or drag an image consisting of multiple shapes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution;

```
Arrange => Group
```